# WebStorm 11 unrecognized MongoDb (with mongoose) functions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, webstorm

WebStorm gives me a warning of "Unrecognized function or method" on functions like:

- Schema.find()  *[find() not recognized]*
- Schema.aggregate() *[aggregate() not recognized]*
- Schema.findOneAndUpdate() *[findOneAndUpdate() not recognized]*

I've tried to Enabling the NodeJs core libraries and to install

- mongodb-DefinitelyType
- mongoose-DefinitelyType
- mongoose-auto-increment-DefinitelyType
- mongoose-deep-populate-DefinitelyType
- mongoose-DefinitelyType
- mongoose-mock-DefinitelyType

under `Preferences > JavaScript > Libraries`

But this has not solved my problem. Does someone knows a solution?

Comment: what does your code look like exactly?  may be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17099

Comment: This workaround solved my problem var MODEL_PATH = '../models/'
var User = require(MODEL_PATH + 'user'), thank you. If you answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17099; please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17099#comment=27-1441265 for possible workaround

Answer (score 3):

This is possible solution working for me without any issues.

Moving the relative path out of the require() statement as follows.

```
const PATH = '../models/';
const User = require(PATH + 'user');
```

**Alternatively**

Do not import Schema separately.

Just import mongoose like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

and use `mongoose.Schema` to access Schema

Comment: thanks, it works just fine... maybe just to use 'path' and '__dir' variables: const path = require('path'); const Post = require(path.join(__dirname,'../models/post'));

Comment: Thanks the first one seems to work fine. But it doesn't make sense why it works like that!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason but somehow this works:

```
export
module.exports.User = User; // your model

import
const User = require("../dbSchema/user.js").User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the schema is inserted correctly. Don't forget to check your Schema.

Sample

```
 module.exports = mongoose.model('SampleCollection', SampleSchema);
```